# Scraping table in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have found a webpage that is proving difficult for me to scrape and I am not exactly sure why. Its table data with a hyperlink in the first column, address and website. What I am trying to do is to scrape the name of and location from the first page, then go into the link, scrape the telephone number and append it to my other list.

Ideally, the CSV would have: title, location, province, link, phone.

I have been trying for days but am running in circles. Please help!

My code is as follows

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl = ["https://www.informa.es/directorio-empresas/0111_CULTIVO-CEREALES-EXCEPTO-ARROZ-LEGUMINOSAS-SEMILLAS-OLEAGINOSAS/Comunidad_CASTILLA-MANCHA.html#empresa"]
urls = [f'https://www.informa.es/directorio-empresas/0111_CULTIVO-CEREALES-EXCEPTO-ARROZ-LEGUMINOSAS-SEMILLAS-OLEAGINOSAS/Comunidad_CASTILLA-MANCHA/Empresas-{i}.html#empresa'.format(i) for i in range(2,38)]


allurls = baseurl + urls
#print(allurls)
data = []
for url in allurls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    lists = soup.select("div#empresas_directorio ul")

    #scrape the pages
    for lis in lists:
        title = lis.find('li', class_="nom_empresa").text
        location = lis.find('span', class_="addressLocality").text
        province = lis.find('span', class_="addressRegion").text
        link = lis.select_one("li.col1 a")['href']
        info = [title, location, province, link]
        #print(info)

        sub_page = requests.get(link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(sub_page.content, "html.parser")
        phone=soup2.select_one('tel')
        telephone = phone.text if phone else None
        #print([title,location,province,link,telephone])
        data.append([title, location, province, link, telephone])


cols = ["title", "location", "province", "link", "telephone"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)
df.to_csv('CSM.csv',index = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What happens?

I am not sure why you selecting `<ul>` and `<li>` in your first part while the data is placed in a table - This way it will not work. In second part you try to get the phone number by selecting a tag `tel` but there is only a `class` with this name.

#### How to fix?

I wont fix all the stuff in details for you just show up how to make the heavy mistakes run.

At first select the rows of the table that keeps the data:

```
soup.select('[itemprop="itemListElement"]')
```

While iterating over the result set, select the elements needed simply by its item property:

```
title = lis.select_one('[itemprop="name"]').text
location = lis.select_one('[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text
province = lis.select_one('[itemprop="addressRegion"]').text
link = lis.select_one('a')['href']
```

Selecting the telephone number from additional request by its class:

```
soup2.select_one('.tel')
```

#### Focused example

```
...

lists = soup.select('[itemprop="itemListElement"]')

#scrape the pages
for lis in lists:
    title = lis.select_one('[itemprop="name"]').text
    location = lis.select_one('[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text
    province = lis.select_one('[itemprop="addressRegion"]').text
    link = lis.select_one('a')['href']
    info = [title, location, province, link]
   
    sub_page = requests.get(link)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(sub_page.content, "html.parser")
    phone=soup2.select_one('.tel')
    telephone = phone.text if phone else None
    data.append([title, location, province, link, telephone])
...
```

#### Output

```
    title   location    province    link    telephone
0   BASCULA AGRARIA SOCIEDAD LIMITADA.  Membrilla   CIUDAD REAL https://www.informa.es/directorio-empresas/Emp...   691262748
1   MARCUNEZ INVERMOL SL    Castillo de Garcimuñoz  CUENCA  https://www.informa.es/directorio-empresas/Emp...   None
2   ALJOFRUIT VERDURAS SOCIEDAD LIMITADA.   Picazo (El) CUENCA  https://www.informa.es/directorio-empresas/Emp...   None
...
```

Comment: So I´ve gone through and adjusted everything, but it still returns empty df´s. Should i not select the whole table instead of the "itemListElement"? I have tried variations of these but it never takes any values.

Comment: @NickGordon: Suggestion, go step by step - 1. Take a look into your soup - Do you get the information you need or some messages with bot detection / blocking / ... 2. Do not iterate over all pages - Just try one and then two of them, cause it needs time to perform and you are penetrating the website unnecessarily. 3...